# (Android) Downloading MP3 file with app (Content not support)

Tags: android

When I download MP3 files with my app they go to the download folder and when I navigate there and try to play them I get content not supported. I have looked around a little bit, but can't figure out why. Anyone know how I can fix this, is it something with the MIME types? What does this do:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "audio/*");
```

Comment: Are you trying to play through you app? Or are you trying to use the default android media player?

Comment: It was after the file was downloaded, but I fixed the problem. I was saving it without the .mp3 extension so all I had to do was add that back. Now I don't know how to get my bounty back...

Comment: Unfortunately your bounty cannot be returned. I'll help you not make it go to waste though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> MP3       •   Mono/Stereo 8-320Kbps constant (CBR) or variable bit-rate
>   (VBR) MP3 (.mp3)

Android Supports MP3 in the above format. Incorrect encoding makes this type of error. Also check to see if the extension and file names are proper. Because some downloaders may name the file like mywebsite.com-mysong.mp3. The android OS may wrongly interpret the file as a .com file rather than a .mp3 file.

**Reference:**

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you save with the .mp3 extension. sometimes it can get lost along the way.